# Angular SignalR is not working with AWS Load Balancer Proxy URL

Tags: angular, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr, amazon-elb

I am using `signalR` between my `Angular` with library `@aspnet/signalr` and `.NET Core` application. It is working fine on local machine and as well on IIS.
I want to use custom `URL` so I have applied Proxy through `AWS Load Balancer` so the API URL looks like `https://api.example.com`. It also works fine with `Load Balancer` URL.

With proxy URL, it gives an error `failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400`. Any suggestions to sort out this issue?

Comment: `Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400` Have set allowed transports to WebSockets only explicitly on Angular client side? And please check if WebSockets protocol is enabled.

Comment: @FeiHan Yes, that's why it is working fine If I point `Load Balancer` URL directly. We are forwarding to a group from `Load Balancer` for custom URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, the main issue was with Network Load Balancer. Later on, we created & tested this with separate Application Load Balancer and It worked fine.